# Method to import excel to sql thru aspnet without using OleDB

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, import-from-excel

Hi is there any UI/controllers for ASPNet(either C# or VB) or any method to read/dump excel to sql without using OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0')?
Your suggestion is highly appreciated...Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help but. I use this connection string with my VB.net Form application.

```
 sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sFileName & ";Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO"""
 sSQL = "Select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL AND F1 <> ''"
Dim OLEConn As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, OLEConn)
Dim OLEAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
OLEAdapter.Fill(dt)
```

Then I use SQL Bulk copy to write the DT to SQL table

```
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 0)
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "SomeTable"
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
```

if you don't use OLEDB, I assume you will need to use excel application object and create a function to iterate to each columns and row to get the data.
http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_2007_open_file.htm

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\test1.xlsx")
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
'display the cells value B2
MsgBox(xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2).value)
'edit the cell with new value
xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2) = "http://vb.net-informations.com"
xlWorkBook.Close()
xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: @BobNoobGuy- thanks but this is using an Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12. We are not permitted to install this Office Interop DLLs...

Comment: I think even opening the excel file you will need excel 12.0 object library (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/15s06t57(v=vs.100).aspx . The only alternative I can think of is if you use "xlsx" not "xls" .. xlsx is basically a zip file where you can extract the SHEET1.xml and get the XML . but that is going to be really messy.